# duplicate entry:junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

When I import the espresso into my gradle file and try to run my app I get this exception.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task   
 ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     
 java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:     
 junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class
```

I did lots of search but still have this problem. This is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "theo.testing.androidespresso"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

 }

 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `build.gradle` dependencies section to:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

}
```

Read carefully: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/

Hope it will help